# Перемещение IMG в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, img

Добрый день, есть IMG c position: relative; и заданы параметры top и left. Но при увеличении экрана, позиция картинки меняется, и надо что-то прописать, чтобы позиция менялась в зависимости от разрешения. Прописывать для каждого разрешения экрана top и left не особо хорошо, поэтому думаю можно в JavaScript сделать, мог бы кто-нибудь помочь с этим?

Приведу пример кода:

```css
.slider-home-map {
  top: -750px;
  left: -380px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="/maps-new-home.png" class="slider-home-map" />
```

Вот в моем разрешении 1280x1024 будет нормально показано, а при разрешении 1440 к примеру уже другое, и чтобы не присваивать каждому разрешению значения, можно сделать javascript код, который при увеличении разрешения на 1 пиксель, будет двигать картинку на 1 пиксель?

Фото с сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
baseWidth = 1024 //базовое разрешение, от которого отталкиваемся
baseHeight = 768
width = window.screen.width //разрешение экрана пользователя
height = window.screen.height
img = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-home-map')[0]; //Получаем элемент изображения из DOM документа
img.style.left += baseWidth - width; //к базовому смещению прибавляем разницу
img.style.top += baseHeight - height;
```

Получится смещение на 1пкс при изменении размера экрана на 1пкс.

А по хорошему таким не занимаются. Подобная проблема решается грамотными стилями и версткой

Answer (score 1):

Для этого используют [Responsive Grids](http://designinstruct.com/web-design/responsive-css-grid/)
Если я правильно понял, то [вот пример](https://codepen.io/emb/pen/ZWVazj?editors=1100#)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92068/pexels-photo-92068.jpeg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92068/pexels-photo-92068.jpeg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, Дело в том что сама картинка в разрешении 3323х1733, и нужно ее разместить по центру и увеличенной, как в примере (Разрешение монитора 1280x1024). И при увеличении разрешения чтобы и менялась сама картинка адаптировалась. Еще забыл упомянуть - под картинкой слайдер, а в коде это все вот так - div slider затем div img и картинке присваивается position: relative; и z-index для того, чтобы она была поверх

Comment: Пробовали позиционировать с помошью `width` и `@media`?